# Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Pues vereis ,estoy tratando de crear tablas a partir  del código generado por **start uml** pero al momento de ejecutar el codigo en phpmyadmin  me doy con la grata sorpresa .

ERROR:

CREATE TABLE `cliente` (

```
`id_cliente` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`nombre_cliente` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`direccion` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`telefono_cliente` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
`ciudad` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
```

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'NOT NULL,

`ciudad` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,

```
`email` VARCHAR(80) NOT NU...' en la linea 5
```

**Lo que trate** fue comentar las lineas para ver  ubicarlo mejor pero no funciono.

Aqui el codigo generado:

````
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cliente`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `vendedor`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orden_pedido`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Det_Opera`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orden_produc`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `materia`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Composicion`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pieza`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Demanda`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

CREATE TABLE `cliente` (
    `id_cliente` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `nombre_cliente` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `direccion` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `telefono_cliente` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `ciudad` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_cliente`)
);

CREATE TABLE `vendedor` (
    `id_vendedor` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `sucursal` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_vendedor`)
);

CREATE TABLE `orden_pedido` (
    `numero` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `fecha_pedido` DATE NOT NULL,
    `cond_pago` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `valor_neto` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `valor_total` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `estado_pedido` NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`numero`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Det_Opera` (
    `can_pedida` INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `orden_produc` (
    `nro_pro` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `fecha_pro` DATE NOT NULL,
    `fecha_incio` DATE NOT NULL,
    `fecha_fin` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`nro_pro`)
);

CREATE TABLE `materia` (
    `cod_materia` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `descripcion` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    `precio` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`cod_materia`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Composicion` (
    `cantidadpieza` INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `pieza` (
    `codigoPieza` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `nombrePieza` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `peso` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `costoPieza` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`codigoPieza`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Demanda` (
    `cantidad_dem` INTEGER NOT NULL
);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que solo definiste:

```
'telefono_cliente' VARCHAR
```

Debes definir una longitud a `VARCHAR`, por ejemplo:

```
'telefono_cliente' VARCHAR(15)
```

Comment: Eyder Alejandro Garcia Vivas, es la solucion te lo agradesco.